# Make sort function with generic types

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, generics

I am writing a sort function for the array of objects. The function args are an array of objects and the key. I am new to typescript but I am trying to make types generic.

But I am getting this error - **Element implicitly has an 'any' type because the expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.**

```
    58 |         sortedData.sort((a, b) => {
    59 |           if (
  > 60 |             stringToDate(a[sortConfig.columnKey]).getTime() >
       |                          ^
    61 |             stringToDate(b[sortConfig.columnKey]).getTime()
    62 |           ) {
    63 |             return sortConfig.direction === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
```

**Here is the function:**

```
function sortFunction<T>(data: T[], sortConfig: SortConfig | null): T[] {
  const sortedData = [...data];
  switch (sortConfig != null && sortConfig.columnKey) {
    case "paidUntilDate":
    case "startDate":
    case "accountEndingDate":
      if (sortConfig != null) {
        sortedData.sort((a, b) => {
          if (
            stringToDate(a[sortConfig.columnKey]).getTime() >
            stringToDate(b[sortConfig.columnKey]).getTime()
          ) {
            return sortConfig.direction === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
          }

          if (
            stringToDate(a[sortConfig.columnKey]).getTime() <
            stringToDate(b[sortConfig.columnKey]).getTime()
          ) {
            return sortConfig.direction === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
          }

          return 0;
        });
      }
      break;
    default:
      if (sortConfig != null) {
        sortedData.sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[sortConfig.columnKey] > b[sortConfig.columnKey]) {
            return sortConfig.direction === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
          }
          if (a[sortConfig.columnKey] < b[sortConfig.columnKey]) {
            return sortConfig!.direction === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
          }

          return 0;
        });
      }
  }
  return sorted data;
}
```

sortConfig is:

```
export interface SortConfig {
  columnKey: string;
  direction: Order_Table_Hook;
}
```

and Order_Table_Hoook is :

```
export type Order_Table_Hook = "asc" | "desc" | undefined;
```

stringToDate:

```
export function stringToDate(dateString: DateAsString): Date {
  return new Date(dateString);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `stringToDate` funciton?

Comment: I just added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Basic Idea

The type of `a` and `b` in the sort callback function will be `T`

and `a[sortConfig.columnKey]` should get a `DateAsString` type to be accepted by `stringToDate` function.

Let's try if this work or not, extends the `T` with `{[k:string]: DateAsString}`

```ts
function sortFunction<T extends {[k: string]: DateAsString}>(data: T[], sortConfig: SortConfig | null): T[]
```

This passes the checking with my default `tsconfig.json`

## For more types

For example, if you wanna support `DateAsString`, `number`, `boolean` for your `MyDataObject` type, you can define it as:

```ts
export type MyDataObject = {
  [k: string]: DateAsString | number | boolean;
};
```

And add `as DateAsString` affix to for `a[sortConfig.columnKey]`

```ts
if(
  stringToDate(a[sortConfig.columnKey] as DateAsString).getTime() >
  stringToDate(b[sortConfig.columnKey] as DateAsString).getTime()
){
  return sortConfig.direction === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
}
```

## Most General

If you can make sure the data type of the value of `paidUntilDate`, `startDate`, `accountEndingDate` will not be other ones but `DateAsString`, then you can do this:

```ts
export type MyDataObject = {
  [k: string]: any
};
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is you cannot have any other types in `T` but `DateAsString`.

Comment: yep, that's the issue.. 